# Move sprite up on touch and set that as starting position

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2D, and stuck at a problem. I also searched a lot but don't seem to find the answer to my problem. The situation is:

When the game starts, the main sprite should keep going down (like a plan crash). If user touches anywhere in the screen, the sprite should move up to the Y-coordinate of the touched point and when the sprite reaches that point, it should start going down again from that point. Imagine a plane crashing (going down) and when user taps anywhere, it goes up (takes off a little) and then again starts to go down. We just don't have to let it crash to the ground.

So, I have achieved the going down part. As well as the going up part. **But the problem is that when the sprite completes going up, it doesn't start to go down from there, rather it continues going down from where it went up.**

Please help me achieve this goal.

Here's my code for going down in the `init()` method:

```
 [plane runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0,-20)],
                                                       nil]]];
```

code for going up in `touchesBegan` method:

```
  [plane runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0,20)]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a repeatable action and once you apply the "move up" action you will have inconsistency as both actions work on the same object (I do not remember if the previous action is canceled but this approach will not work).

So I would do the followng for `init()` :

```
.
.
[self startDownMovement];
.
.
```

Then implement `startDownMovement()` as :

```
[plane runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0,-plane.potision.y)],
                                     [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:
                                     ^{
                                           // Do game over logic. (i.e. plain crashed)
                                      }],nil]];
```

And for the `touchBegan()` :

```
 [plane stopAllActions];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
 [plane runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0,location.y)],
                                      [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:
                                      ^{
                                           [self startDownMovement];
                                      }],nil]];
```

What I did here is start the movement down (I assume y=0 is the crashing point) so I move the sprite by minus its y position.

If the user touches the screen the plane y position will be moved to the touching point after which the down movement will be called again (since I used CCSequence moving down will occur only after moving up action has finished)